# Multiple relationships of the same type but with different properties between the same two nodes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Can I create multiple relationships of the same type between the same two nodes?  I am trying to discover patterns in nodes connected with the same relationship type.  For e.g., relation PERFORMED_BY could have a property to record Person1 as the performer with a timestamp for the transition from node A to node B and a second relation PERFORMED_BY could have Person2 as the performer at a different time between the same two nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have multiple relationships of the same type between the same two nodes in Neo4j. And the properties on the different relationships are independent from each other.

It would be useful if you describe your domain a bit more, at least if you want any input on the graph structure!

Comment: Thanks. It does allow this but unfortunately neoclipse (visualizer) only shows the last one.

Comment: Yes, that's a limitation of Neoclipse. You could try generating graphviz instead, see: https://github.com/neo4j/community/tree/master/graphviz