# How to model a relational database into a neo4j graph database?

Tags: neo4j, relational-database, graph-databases

I have a relational database (about 30 tables) and I would like to transpose it in a neo4j graph database, and I don't know where to start...
Is there a general way to transpose tables and/or tuples into a graph model ? (relations properties, one or more graphs ?)  What are the best sources of documentation ?

Thanks for any help,

Best regards

Comment: I guess that the problem is "What do you want to model in it?". IF you talk about a plain move from a Relational model to a Graph mode, I imagine you are doing it wrong. Use them of them for the part you think they can do better.

Comment: What benefit do you hope to realize with this ?  Why would you want to go back to procedural data manipulation like it was done in the 60's and 70's ?

Answer (score 3):

First, if at all possible, I'd suggest NOT using your relational DB as your "reference" for transposing to a graph model.  All too often, mistakes and pitfalls from relational modelling get transferred over to the graph model and introduce other oddities.  In fact, if you have a source ER diagram, that might be an even better starting point as it's really already a graph.  And maybe even consider a re-modelling exercise for your domain!

That said, from a basic point of view, you can think of most tables as representing a node type (e.g. "User" or "Movie") with join tables and keys representing relationship types.

A great starting point, from my perspective anyway, is to determine some questions your graph/data source should answer.  Write those questions down, and try to come up with Cypher queries that represent the questions.  Often times, a graph model naturally arises from such an effort, and it's really not that difficult.

If you haven't already, I'd strongly recommend picking up a (free) copy of the Graph Databases ebook from here: http://graphdatabases.com/

It's jam-packed with a lot of good info on where to start with modelling your domain and even things to consider when you're used to doing things in a relational manner.  It also contains some material on Cypher, although the Neo4j site (neo4j.org) has a reference manual with plenty of up-to-date info on Cypher.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

There's not going to be a one-stop-shop for this kind of conversion, as not all data models are appropriate for graph modeling, and every application is a unique special snowflake...but with that said.....

Generally, your 'base' tables (e.g. User, Role, Order, Product) would become nodes, and your 'join tables' (a.k.a. buster tables) would be candidates for your relationships (e.g. UserRole, OrderLineItem).  The key thing to remember that in a graph, generally, you can only have one relationship of a given type between two specific nodes - so in the above example, if your system allows the same product to be in an order twice - it would cause issues.

Foreign keys are your second source of relationships, look to them to see if it makes sense to be a relationship or just a property.

Just keep in mind what you are trying to solve by your data model - if it's traversing your objects to find relationships and distance, etc... then graphs may be a good fit.  If you are modeling an eCommerce app, where you are dealing with manipulating a single nested object (e.g. order -> line item -> product -> sku), then a relational model may be the right fit.

Hope my $0.02 helps...

Comment: +1, but note that in neo4j, you *can* have multiple edges of the same type between nodes - see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601346/multiple-relationships-of-the-same-type-but-with-different-properties-between-th)

Comment: wow... thanks... I totally thought you could only have one =(A)-[r:REL_TYPE]-(B)... opens up a lot more models

Answer (score 0):

As has been already said, there is no magical transformation from a relational database model to a graph database model.

You should look for the original entities and how they are related in order to find your nodes, properties and relations. And always keeping in mind what type of queries you are going to perform.

As **BtySgtMajor** said, ["Graph Databases"](http://graphdatabases.com/) is a good book to start, and it is free.