# Convert database data into graph with tinkerpop tools

Tags: graph, tinkerpop

I am looking to find graph software that will create a graph from a database automatically. Upon exploration of the tinkerpop documentation, the provided tutorials discuss querying ready-made graphs but there is not much about creating graphs from a database. Is it possible to use any of the tools in the tinkerpop suite to automatically convert data from a database into a graph ready for querying?

Let's say we have an event stream like this:

```
event_type=create_file name="filename.txt" handle=1
event_type=read handle=1 data="file content"
event_type=write handle=1 data="new file content"
event_type=close handle=1
```

Is there a way to convert the event stream into a graph automatically by specifying which properties to follow for creating edges? For example, by selecting the "**handle**" property I should get:

```
create_file-->read-->write-->close
```

All the examples I could find teach me how to do some activity like

```
add_node create_file
add_node read
add_node write
add_node close
```

followed by adding all desired edges manually.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are suggesting is simply not possible. A graph database is very different from a traditional relational database. The biggest difference being that graphs are naturally unstructured which allow for more flexibility and manipulation. On the other hand, traditional relational or tabular databases are more rigidly structured which provide less flexibility but easier control and querying.

As stated by the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765524/how-to-model-a-relational-database-into-a-neo4j-graph-database) you also show not be using your original database as a frame of reference. You should instead be thinking about how to manipulate your data into a graph so as to take advantage of graphs.

For example, a **traversal** in a graph as opposed to a **query** in a tabular DB is a lot more flexible (and arguably powerful) but harder to construct and formalise.

There is a lot of good material providing guidelines for how to approach this problem [[1]](http://graphdatabases.com/) [[2]](http://www.slideshare.net/AntonioMaccioni/grades-27491364) [[3]](http://neo4j.com/developer/graph-db-vs-rdbms/) [[4]](http://www.inf.uniroma3.it/~torlone/pubs/grades2014.pdf). Unfortunately though there is no **good** automated migration at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-etl-components/ which is a very interesting tool. It takes an RDBMS schema and generates a graph representation, turning foreign keys and join tables into relationships, and (other) tables into nodes in the graph. And then it generates CSV files to load into a graph database, either for wholesale or incremental updates.

I don't know if there's an equivalent tool for Tinkerpop. But I'd hope that since much of the work is done (reading the SQL schema, mapping tables with foreign keys into vertices and edges) in this open source project, perhaps it'd be a good starting point?

The output of the tool looks like it depends on having a clean source data model, and may be naive. It looks like it's configurable so when it guesses wrongly about which tables are vertices and which are edges you can override it I think.